# MCC, MNC, CID, tac returns same value 2147483647.... Any solution for this issue?

Tags: android, cordova-plugins

> Return the MCC,MNC,TAC same as Interger.MAX_VALUE I.e. 2147483647
> **Any solution for this ?**

```
private void getAllCellInfos(){
    if(_telephonyManager != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        final List<CellInfo> cellInfos = _telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
        processCellInfos(cellInfos);
    }
    else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to provide cell info due to version restriction");
    }
}
```

> Method to check network

```
 private static void processCellInfos(List<CellInfo> cellInfos){
    if(cellInfos != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

        for(CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfos){

            if(cellInfo instanceof  CellInfoWcdma){
                final CellInfoWcdma cellInfoWcdma = (CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo;
                sendCallback(PluginResult.Status.OK,
                        JSONHelper.cellInfoWCDMAJSON(cellInfoWcdma, _returnSignalStrength));
            }
            if(cellInfo instanceof CellInfoGsm){
                final CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) cellInfo;
                sendCallback(PluginResult.Status.OK,
                        JSONHelper.cellInfoGSMJSON(cellInfoGsm, _returnSignalStrength));
            }
            if(cellInfo instanceof  CellInfoCdma){
                final CellInfoCdma cellIdentityCdma = (CellInfoCdma) cellInfo;
                sendCallback(PluginResult.Status.OK,
                        JSONHelper.cellInfoCDMAJSON(cellIdentityCdma, _returnSignalStrength));
            }
            if(cellInfo instanceof  CellInfoLte){
                final CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) cellInfo;
                sendCallback(PluginResult.Status.OK,
                        JSONHelper.cellInfoLTEJSON(cellInfoLte, _returnSignalStrength));
            }

            Log.d(TAG,cellInfo.toString());
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "CellInfoLocation returning null. Is it supported on this phone?");

        // There are several reasons as to why cell location data would be null.
        // * could be an older device running an unsupported version of the Android OS
        // * could be a device that doesn't support this capability.
        // * could be incorrect permissions: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        sendCallback(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,
                JSONHelper.errorJSON(CELLINFO_PROVIDER, ErrorMessages.CELL_DATA_IS_NULL()));
    }
}
```

> Retrives values from device

```
public static String cellInfoLTEJSON(CellInfoLte cellInfo, boolean returnSignalStrength){

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 && cellInfo != null) {
        try {
            json.put("provider", CELLINFO_PROVIDER);
            json.put("type", LTE);
            json.put("timestamp", calendar.getTimeInMillis());

            final CellIdentityLte identityLte = cellInfo.getCellIdentity();

            json.put("ci", identityLte.getCi());
            json.put("mcc", identityLte.getMccString());
            json.put("mnc", identityLte.getMncString());
            json.put("pci", identityLte.getPci());
            json.put("tac", identityLte.getTac());

            if (returnSignalStrength){
                final JSONObject jsonSignalStrength = new JSONObject();
                final CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrengthLte = cellInfo.getCellSignalStrength();
                jsonSignalStrength.put("asuLevel", cellSignalStrengthLte.getAsuLevel());
                jsonSignalStrength.put("dbm", cellSignalStrengthLte.getDbm());
                jsonSignalStrength.put("level", cellSignalStrengthLte.getLevel());
                jsonSignalStrength.put("timingAdvance", cellSignalStrengthLte.getTimingAdvance());

                json.put("cellSignalStrengthLte", jsonSignalStrength);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException exc) {
            logJSONException(exc);
        }
    }
    return json.toString();
}
```

> some times it returns actual values but most of the time it returns 2147483647.

Correct values:

> "ci": "205258256",
> "eNb": "901790",
> "cid": "230858275",
> "tac": "4111",
> "pci": "476",
> "earfcn": "39175",
> "rssi": "-119",
> "rsrp": "-119",
> "rsrq": "-17",
> "mcc": "404",
> "mnc": "92"

Incorrect values

> "ci": "2147483647",
> "eNb": "801790",
> "cid": "205258246",
> "tac": "2147483647",
> "pci": "59",
> "earfcn": "1425",
> "rssi": "-105",
> "rsrp": "-105",
> "rsrq": "-20",
> "mcc": "2147483647",
> "mnc": "2147483647"

[Correct values extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN0CE.png)

[Incorrect values extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw6Y3.png)

Comment: They [return int.MAX_VALUE if it's unavailable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm?hl=en#getCid()). There isn't a solution - it isn't available on whatever device you test it on.

Comment: i am testing it on "Redmi Note 5 Pro" device and it sometimes return the correct expected values and most of the time incorrect ones on the same device.